# How to get rootViewController in didAccept method of GameKit in a SwiftUI application?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game in SwiftUI.
Everything works as expected except when inviting a player if the person being invited has already opened the game.

The didAccept method is then called as expected. Only I don't know how to find the rootViewController in a SwiftUI application to present the created viewController.

Does anyone know how to find the rootViewController or how to fix this?

The code is as follows:

```
final func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite) {

    print("didAccept")
    
    if let matchmakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(invite: invite) {
        
        print("accepted")
        
        matchmakerViewController.matchmakerDelegate = self
        
        //if let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController {
        if let rootViewController = UIApplication.rootViewController {
            
            rootViewController.present(matchmakerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        } else {
            
            print("No rootViewController")
            
        }
        
    }
  
}
```

```
extension UIApplication {
    static var currentKeyWindow: UIWindow? {            
        UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
        .map { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .first?.windows
        .filter { $0.isKeyWindow }
        .first
        
    }
                
    static var rootViewController: UIViewController? { 
        currentKeyWindow?.rootViewController
    }            
}
```

And the console prints:

"didAccept"
"accepted"
"No rootViewController"

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Kristof

Hello everybody,

As Son suggested, I modified my code and now use the struct below as a View in a sheet to show the invitation window:

```
struct MultiplayerGameView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    private var viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController
    
    init(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController) {
        
        self.viewController = viewController
        
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GKMatchmakerViewController {
        
        return self.viewController
        
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, context: Context) {
    }

}
```

As far as I can judge now, everything seems to be working as expected.

Kind regards,
Kristof

Comment: Using the root view controller in this fashion isn’t good practice for meany reasons you should interface with a UIViewControllerRepresentable if using SwiftUI